# Why to store salt along with hashed password in database

Tags: security, encryption, hash

I am currently working on a system where I need to store the hashed password. 
I am using `cryptographically secure pseudo-random number generator`**(CSPRNG)** for generating the `salt`. I am using the `PBKDF2` for hashing the password appended with the `salt` which finally will be stored in the database.

What I am not getting is why do I even need to store the `salt` along with the `hashed password` in the database. I do understand the purpose of the `salt`. It significantly reduces the chance of a successful `rainbow and lookup` attacks. Also users with same password will have different hashes stored in the database.

So where is the need comes for storing the salt in the database?

**UPDATE:**

> I should have mentioned this earlier, but that time it didnt click me. The `password` here is never going to be provided by the user. It is for our internal purpose. We just need it to be generated for the first time user comes to our website, and later on we will just send this `Hashed` password in the response.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### What if we don't salt?

You already understand at this point that if you use `Password1` on its own (without a salt) then every time you hash it, you will get the exact same result. Now, let's pretend you have 1000 users and of those 1000, 25 of them use the same password. Those 25 hashes are going to be *exactly the same*. Once an attacker gains access to your database and finds the hash `70ccd9007338d6d81dd3b6271621b9cf9a97ea00` translates to `Password1`, they will have gained access to 25 people's accounts in no time at all. This means a rainbow table attack will allow him to access more accounts, faster.

### What if we do salt?

By appending a salt to the value of `Password1` you are going to dramatically change the hash. Each user should have their own salt. This means that even if you have all 1000 of your users using `Password1`, all 1000 hashes will be completely different. In real real world, this means that the 25 of your 1000 users who have the same exact password will all have different hashes. However, it also means an attacker will have to run an attack on one password at a time, rather than just rainbow tabling the hashes and hoping for the best.

### But why do we store the salt?

Without the salt, you won't be able to recreate the hash when the user enters their password - meaning the user can never log in again and access their account. By storing the password, you can allow the user to enter their password and then you run a lookup on their account, append the salt to their input, and hash the entire thing; if it matches the hash stored in the database you've got the right password! If you never store this salt, you can never recreate the hash!

I hope this explains a little better, and as always if you have any comments feel free to ask

Comment: u said "Once an attacker gains access to your database and finds the hash", dont it also can find the salt? so what's the point of storing salt in db?

Comment: @kevin My understanding is the whole point of salts is to render precomputed attacks like rainbow table attacks ineffective since now, an attacker would have to build rainbow tables for every salt value they encounter.

Answer (score 2):

The output of PBKDF2 is dependent on the salt. If you don't store the salt, then there is no way for you to determine if the password is correct.

It is safe to store the salt with the password hash, just ensure the salt is random for every password.

Comment: I got your point. But I have updated our system requirements. In that approach I dont think we need to save the ''salt".

Comment: So you never need to compute the hash ever again?  Why use it at all then?

Comment: Problem is, this "hashed" password will be sent to the user and it will be used for further third party tool authentication. If i just save a random string generated by **CSPRNG** and send it to the user , then the problem will boil down to how easy is to guess that string(of same length for all the users) ?

Comment: Are you using this to just generate a random token?

Comment: basically, Yes.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/171521/discussion-between-manya-and-luke-joshua-park).

Answer (score 0):

> `what's the point of storing salt in db?`

When the user registers, they enter `username` & `pwd`, then we do below:
. generate (random) `registration salt`, combine with this `registration pwd`, then generate `registration hash`
. now we store `registration salt` & `registration hash`, this means we don't store `registration pwd` so someone does not get pwd right away, they will have to hacker to get back the pwd which is a very lengthy process if we use a good salt & hash algorithm to generate a good hash

When the user is at login page, they enter `username` & `pwd`, then we do below:
. retrieve the (same) `registration salt`, combine with this `LOGIN pwd`, then generate `LOGIN hash`
. retrieve the `registration hash` & compare with `LOGIN hash`
. if both `registration hash` & `LOGIN hash` are same, it is correct password, user is allowed to see website
. else login fails